# char* array brakes with more then 6 values

Tags: arrays, arduino

I have been all day around this and can´t understand where is the problem.
I'm using a Nokia LCD screen to print a number (2 digits) that I draw myself.

Each number (0 to 9) is composed by an array, like so:

```
char Number_0[] = {0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0xC4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xE4, 0xC4, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x87, 0xCF, 0xCF, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x87, 0xCF, 0xCF, 0x87, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x81, 0x83, 0x83, 0x8D, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x9E, 0x8D, 0x83, 0x83, 0x81};
```

To be able to point to each Number Array, I'm using another array, with the List of the Array Numbers, like so:

```
char* NumberList[] = {Number_0, Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6, Number_7, Number_8, Number_9};
```

To print the number unto the screen I use the funtion:

```
int Number = 30;
void PrintNumber(){
  int Unit = int(Number / 10);
  LCDBitmap(DigitalList[Unit]); //should Print 3
  Unit = Number - Unit * 10;
  LCDBitmap(DigitalList[Unit]); //should Print 0
}
```

LCDBitmap, is another function, that is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

For some reason, this does not work, unless I remove 4 values from NumberList[].
As long as I have only 6 values, it will work, doesn't matter with one I remove, but as son as I add a 7º one... the code brakes.

Any idea?

Comment: why are you using char* instead of char[][]?

Comment: to Mike: If I use only char, I get the error: "invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'", and of course each value of NumberList[] is a pointer.

Comment: yes, so: why are you not using char[][], which is the syntax for "an array of char arrays".

Comment: sorry, I miss understood your question. Since apparently, as Ignacio pointed it, I'm running out of SRAM, using char[][] was crashing instantly my code. With hes proposal, hopefully I will be able to use char[][]... more news as soon as I implement and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations, you're out of SRAM. Since this LUT isn't going to be changing at runtime it should be [placed in flash](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html) instead.

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

 ...

char Number_0[] PROGMEM = {0x04, ...};
 ...
char* NumberList[] PROGMEM = {Number_0, ...};
```

You then use `pgm_read_word()` to read the location from `NumberList`, and then `pgm_read_byte()` to read the specific values from `Number_x`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this right now, but first I need to grasp the concept you are exposing... back to the learning.